# Regext match end of string

Tags: regex

Can anyone please help me figure out why the following regex cannot match? I need to validate that the string starts with "rect(" or "rect (" and ends with ")"

```
rect (a,a,a,a)
```

Regex

```
(^rect+\s*\()+\)$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the `(` and `)`:

```
^rect\s*\(.*\)$
```

This is needed because parenthesis usually have special meaning in regular expressions, so if you want to match a literal `(` or `)` it should be escaped.

This will match:

- the start of the string
- a literal `rect`
- zero or more whitespace characters
- a literal `(`
- zero or more of any character
- a literal `)`
- the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

Use the following one:
    `^rect\s*\(.*\)$`

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you:

```
^rect\s*\(.*?\)$
```